# What to call a rigorous theorem that is outlined and not stated rigorously in a funding proposal

Tags: terminology

I am adding more background for this question:

I want to sketch the **statement** of a complicated and long theorem in the introduction part of a funding proposal, and later make reference to it, but not like applying it inside a proof, just referring to this theorem/result.

I also want to avoid the actual precise statement of the theorem in the entire proposal.

This is why I wonder what name I should use for this. I do not want a long name, since names like **Outline of the Theorem 1.12** look weird as a reference, compared to **Proposition 1.12**, **Lemma 1.12**, etc.

Is there a single word that could work? I was initially using "**Remark 1.12**" but it still feels weird.

Comment: Conjecture?....

Comment: I don’t understand how a rigorous theorem can be outlined, but not stated rigorously…

Comment: I'd call it an outline of a theorem.

Comment: maybe "sketch proof" ?

Comment: I have added more details to my question

Comment: You want money. Would you fund a proposal that promises to produce just "***Outlines*** of Theorems", "Propositions" or "Lemmas" ? Pitch as high as you can.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: you have this theorem, which is rigorous and true, and you want to state it in a kind of intuitive way which is not rigorous, and then reference it(?) maybe I would try something like "Result"

Comment: @alvoi Thanks, I think "result" should work!